# Large Application - How to handle data access

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, azure

I have a large enterprise web application that is starting to be heavily used. Recently I've noticed that we are making many database calls for things like user permissions, access, general bits of profile information.

From what I can see on Azure we are looking at an average of 50,000 db queries per hour.

We are using Linq to query via the DevExpress XPO ORM. Now some of these are joins, but the majority are simple 1 table queries.

Is constantly hitting the database the best way to be accessing this kind of information? Are there ways for us to offload the database work as some of this information will never change?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is far to broad and unspecific. We can´t know your settings, so can´t suggest improvements. Even *if* you´d provided those this question was too broad because there are dozens of optimization-opportunities. Furthermore what you consider "heavily used" and "lots of db-calls" might be relevant. In particular it´s not Linq *or* stored procedure, it could also be an addition. Neither the one nor the other makes any difference, they completely depend on *how* you´re using them.

Comment: Thanks mate, sorry the question was way to vague. I've re-worded it hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: 50K queries per hour isn't large. The standard guidance applies. Don't assume the database is slow, it's always your code. Use proper schemas, indexes. Don't load stuff you don't want. Don't use the ORM for reports. Use optimistic concurrency. Don't use transactions because someone misunderstood the meaning of `transaction per request`.

Comment: BTW if you do joins in LINQ you have several design bugs already. It means you didn't specify relations and navigation properties on the ORM configuration. Why join Customer and Order when you can retrieve `Order.Customer` ?

Comment: Don´t try to optimize your product without *measuing* what exactly goes slow. Is it actually your db-call? Or some other logic in your software? You definitly should use a profiler like DotTrace from JetBrains to get to know where exactly things get slow and if they are even worth the afford on doing [premature optimization - as it´s the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I guess 50k per hour isn't many, but when you go from a few hundred to 10's of thousands per customer I was just wanting to get ahead of things to make sure make sure we are not going to crash and burn.

Comment: I will give DotTrace a go today to and start profiling.

Comment: Ah, no. You are on azure, USE IT. Astonishing how people ignore what they have.

Comment: Start: Application Insights on your app.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-profiler

Answer (score 2):

Let's start putting this into perspective. With 3600 seconds in an hour you have less than 20 operations per second. Pathetically low in any measurement.

That said, there is nothing wrong with for example caching user permissions for let's say 30 seconds or a minute.

Generally try to cache not in your code, but IN FRONT - the ASP.NET output cache and donut caching are concepts mostly ignored but still most efficient.

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/donut-caching-and-donut-hole-caching-with-aspnet-mvc-4

has more information. Then ignore all the large numbers and run a profiler - see what your real heavy hitters are (likely around permissions as those are used on every page). Put that into a subsystem and cache this. Given that you can preload that into user identity object in the asp.net subsystem - your code should not hit the database in the pages anyway, so the cache is isolated in some filter in asp.net.

Measure. Make sure your SQL is smart - EF and LINQ lead to extremely idiotic SQL because people are too lazy. Avoid instantiating complete objects just to throw them away, ask only for the fields you need. Make sure your indices are efficient. Come back when you start having a real problem (measured).

But the old rule is: cache early. And LINQ optimization is quite far in the back.

Comment: Mentioning LINQ and joins in the question suggests there are already problems with the ORM configuration. I'd also add `Don't use transactions because you think optimistic concurrency is tricky` and `Forget about transaction per request, it didn't mean database transactions`. These two are enough to make badly written ORM code behave orders of magnitude worse than VB6 and ADO code

Comment: Just made a quick change to the question, we are not actually using transactions. I used the wrong word :)

Comment: Thanks Tom, I will look into this along with the profiling.

Answer (score 0):

For getting user specific information like profile, access etc. from database, instead of fetching it for every request it is better to get information once at the time of login and keep it session. This should reduce your transactions with database